# How do kernel wait queues solve "lost wake up"?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I read the book **Linux Kernel Development**, and have some problems with the example it gives in sleeping and waking up section.

```c
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
add_wait_queue(q, &wait);
while (!condition) {
    prepare_to_wait(&q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if (signal_pending(current))
        /* handle signal */
    schedule();
}
finish_wait(&q, &wait);
```

What will happen if a wake_up comes just before `prepare_to_wait()` and after the while condition? Will the `wake_up` be lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the wakeup will be lost.

`prepare_to_wait()` must be called *before* the condition is checked.
(This is what you will see in real code.)

Comment: So this means the book makes a mistake?

Comment: This means you have found *one* of the mistakes. (I was not able find an errata list for the 3rd edition.)